# Python SNMP module to process more than 10000 OIDs significantly faster

Tags: python, performance, snmp

I'm presently stuck at a point where my python netsnmp module's snmpget command is taking more than 1 hour to complete querying more than 10000 OIDs in hand.
I'm curious to know if there are any modules, which can improve performance of snmpget bringing down the total time. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are those OID's all on one device or not?

Comment: Yes, they are all on one device.

Comment: Than it is possible that the device is bottleneck.

Comment: Try to use snmp4j . You can write program to query oids in batch . Like 10 oids within a SnmpBulk request and fine tune the number